# can't call onNewIntent

Tags: android

My program has MainActivity and myService.

MainActivity is `'singletop'`, and MainActivity overrides `onNewIntent` class.

myService is '**foreground**' Service.
It pop up a notification.
The notification has `Intent(this,MainActivity.class)` in pendingIntent to start MainActivity.

My program's flow is

Launch from icon (start) MainActivity (`startService`) myService (`send broadcast`) broadcast `class(start MainActivity)onNewIntent@MainActivity`

When program is Launched like this flow, onNewIntent is called exactly.

But when program is Launched from notification,
onNewIntent never called.

Launch from Notification `(start) MainActivity (startService) myService (send broadcast) broadcast class(start MainActivity)onNewIntent@MainActivity`

Answer (score 0):

From the guide at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Similarly, a new instance of a "singleTop" activity may also be created to handle a new intent. However, if the target task already has an existing instance of the activity at the top of its stack, that instance will receive the new intent (in an onNewIntent() call); a new instance is not created. In other circumstances — for example, if an existing instance of the "singleTop" activity is in the target task, but not at the top of the stack, or if it's at the top of a stack, but not in the target task — a new instance would be created and pushed on the stack.

Thus onNewIntent is only called if there is an existing instance of the activity at the top of the stack.